# How to create a medieval army secretly?

Tags: society, politics, medieval, religion, history

My story takes place in a Middle Ages world. A fog has appeared all around the country, and no one knows why, but it makes you get sick. They have never seen a disease like that, it's very contagious (only by touching) and you may die in two days if you don't survive (but surviving takes a horrible price, but that is not the point).

A girl, that knows a lot about medicine has the cure and does not want to share it with anyone because she wants to use her knowledge in order to overthrow the King and become queen of the kingdom.

As she needs to create an army to fight against the King she starts to cure people and make others immune in order to have someone by her side.The King does not know how to stop the fog and helping his people, so he starts to search the reasons for it but does not have a clue.

The girl has a building in the vicinity of a city, far and small enough not to call the attention of the King where she helps the people and creates her army. There some people could stay to sleep and eat not to return to the city and maybe being discovered, but it’s not very big, so some people should go back to their houses and maybe they would tell everything without knowing, what would end very badly for the girl, because she would lose her opportunity to overthrow the King.

There is a nobleman friend of hers that takes the sick people to the building in order to get help, so it’s not a problem how she gets the people. The problem is that she has to do it in a hidden way and that would be difficult because an army should be huge, but she can’t give so many people as much a bedroom to sleep in.

So my question is: if she does not have room enough for so many people and they have to leave the building and return home, how can she make everyone to stay by her side?

I know that she saved all of them so maybe they are grateful, but how could she make sure know one is going to tell the King?

For this question I though that maybe she can convince them that she is a goddess and that she is going to stop the King (a lot of people hate him because he only care about war and being more powerful) and save everyone from the disease.

My head is a bit messy now. I'm sorry if this is written wrong, but I'm not an English speaker so it's difficult. Thank you!

Comment: During the Middle Ages, politics was very much survival-of-the-strongest. The king wasn't very special - just the strongest. Weak kings were often invaded, usurped, assassinated, or otherwise overthrown by other ambitious peers and subjects - sometimes with an army, sometimes not. It seems likely that the "nobleman friend"  (who, as a middle-ages noble, was a *sworn vassal* of the king) would not be particularly interested in altruism not justice, and would use her to further their own ambitions.

Comment: Note to close voters: the OP cannot improve his question if you don't explain why you're voting to close (simply clicking on "close" and reading the reasons doesn't explain much).  Personally, this site hosts questions about medieval activities all the time.  I suspect the list of methods for raising a medieval army (from paying for mercenaries to charismatic leadership) is very focused and on-topic for worldbuilding.

Comment: I've cast the final close vote. As the close notice says, this question is more about creating a plot, rather than building a word. As such, it seems off-topic for Worldbuilding Stack Exchange.

Comment: On this web site many many people seem to believe that "medieval" means "everybody is poor except noblemen who are rich". You should really try to find out how the medieval world worked. In particular, in medieval times an "army" was assembled *only* when needed; it consisted of the armsmen of the lord who assembled it, plus his top vassals and *their* armsmen, plus the top vassals of those vassals and their armsmen etc. There is not such thing as a "secret" medieval army; the very essence of the medieval world was its hierarchical structure, which by naturally *had* to be public knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

**Model your heroine after Joan of Arc.**
[image: Joan of Arc]

from https://techgnotic.deviantart.com/journal/Collection-Joan-of-Arc-494537854

http://www.stjoan-center.com/military/stephenr.html

> The firsthand sources make clear that the most obvious and stunning
>   impact of Joan’s leadership was the way in which her charismatic
>   personality hauled the morale of the often-defeated French army up
>   from the pit of cynicism and despair to a fevered high of renewed
>   enthusiasm and collective ardor for battle. Conversely, once her
>   reputation for bringing victory to the French became established, her
>   presence infected the heretofore invincible English with doubt and
>   fear.

Your heroine cannot be a creepy witch.  She must be a charismatic leader.  She has strongly in her favor the fact that she can work bona fide miracles.  You *want* the people she has cured to tell their friends about her.  Not all of her followers need to be people she has cured - people just need to know she is a charismatic leader who has been blessed with the power to cure.  She does not need the nobleman, or not for long.  The people will bring themselves.  I sure as heck would go, sick or not.  I would want her to know whose side I am on: hers.  A person who can work miracles probably has other abilities, known or not.  In a time of crisis, fear and death, what better than a leader who has been blessed by gifts from God?